# Is there a shorter way of writing `StringPtr ? StringPtr : "null"`?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I have this code:

```
 std::wstringstream outstream;
 outstream << (prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName 
             ? prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName 
             : L"null") << L";"
           << (prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject 
             ? prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject 
             : L"null") << L";"
           << (prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine 
             ? prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine
             : L"null") << L";"
           << ... // some more strings here
```

Is there a way to avoid code duplication and still have concise code?

Comment: Just make a function or that accepts a StringPtr, and then runs your ternary conditional operator : outstream << ValueOrNull(prop.m_longname) << L";" where ValueOrNull(strptr s) { return s ? s ? L"null"; } -- Obviously this is psuedo-code and needs to be formatted to your project accordingly.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, I was just about to suggest a macro as an option as well :D

Comment: @Duck: macros don't respect namespaces, and it would be difficult to implement this without evaluating the argument twice. A function would be much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a small function:

```
whatever_t strOrNull(whatever_t str) {
    return str ? str : L"null";
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
std::wstringstream outstream;
outstream << strOrNull(prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName)   << L";"
          << strOrNull(prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject) << L";"
          << strOrNull(prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine)   << L";"
          << ... // some more strings here
```

Or if you wanted to be even more concise, you could do this (depending on what `whatever_t` is; if `wstringstream` already has an `operator<<` overload for that type, this won't work):

```
wstringstream& operator<<(wstringstream& out, whatever_t str) {
    if (str)
        out << str;
    else
        out << L"null";

    return out;
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
std::wstringstream outstream;
outstream << prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName   << L";"
          << prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject << L";"
          << prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine   << L";"
          << ... // some more strings here
```

Comment: Congratulations on being the first of many nearly identical answers.

Comment: @Mark see if that's any better.

Comment: There was no need to apologize or update your answer - my congratulations were genuine. It was an obvious answer, but the first across the finish line deserves the prize.

Comment: `whatever_t` is most likely `wchar_t*`, in which case there is already an overload for `operator<<`.

Answer (score 2):

A function, or a lambda:

```
auto foo = [](const wchar * p) { return p ? p : L"null;" };

outstream << foo(prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName) << L";"
          << foo(prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject) << L";"
          << ...etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple function should do the trick.

```
wchar_t* filterNullString(wchar_t* str)
{
  static wchar const* nullStr = L"null";
  return str ? str : nullStr;
}

std::wstringstream outstream;
outstream << filterNullString(prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName) << L";"
           << filterNullString(prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject)<< L";"
           << filterNullString(prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine)<< L";" ;
```

Comment: Does the `static` modifier change something here? I thought literals are stored in a non-modifiable stringpool anyway ... OK, this is implementation dependant but should be the case for all major compilers with optimization switched on, right?

Comment: @Felix the `static` makes the variable not have to be created every time the function is called. While the string may still be stored in a non-modifiable string pool anyway, the `static` eliminates a little unnecessary work.

Comment: It may be part of the C++ standard, but i was not sure, so i made sure i was doing things right.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper function:

```
const wchar_t *SafeOutput(const wchar_t *str)
{
    return str ? str : L"null";
}
// Analogous function for ANSI strings
...
outstream << SafeOutput(prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName)   << L";"
          << SafeOutput(prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject) << L";"
          << SafeOutput(prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine)   << L";"
          << ... // more strings here
```

Answer (score 2):

The other examples are really good. There is another option, though I wouldn't recommend it (only mentioning for completeness).

GCC has an extension called "Conditionals with Omitted Operands" Which basically looks like this:

```
x = a ?: b;
```

which is the same as (in simple cases like yours, see below for more info):

```
x = a ? a : b;
```

Just less portable. So you **could** write:

```
std::wstringstream outstream;
outstream << (prop.m_pwszOriginalVolumeName   ?: L"null") << L";"
          << (prop.m_pwszSnapshotDeviceObject ?: L"null") << L";"
          << (prop.m_pwszOriginatingMachine   ?: L"null") << L";"
```

But like I said, I **would not** recommend this, I would use a helper function like the other answers mention.

There actually is a case where it performs differently than a regular ternary if, and that's if evaluating `a` has side effects. From the page:

> In this simple case, the ability to omit the middle operand is not
>   especially useful. When it becomes useful is when the first operand
>   does, or may (if it is a macro argument), contain a side effect. Then
>   repeating the operand in the middle would perform the side effect
>   twice. Omitting the middle operand uses the value already computed
>   without the undesirable effects of recomputing it.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html

Comment: Not exactly the same: it only evaluates `a` once.